# Redirect with rails but keep original referral URL for Google Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, seo

I'm have a url that end users enter, for example

```
    example.com/cool_things
```

which after hitting the action in my controller, does a redirect to:

```
    example.com/uber_things
```

Google is not recording any data that users hit the cool_things endpoint.  Here my controller action:

```
    def blah
      redirect_to uber_things_path
    end
```

How can I adjust the redirect so that google will still record the original link in analytics, but the controller will still redirect properly.  Would this be accomplished by just adding a status 301? With just the standard redirect_to in the rails controller google analytics is not recording the user ever entered the "cool_things" endpoint.  Not sure the best practice for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to specify the referrer in ruby (though there's certainly got to be a way) but you can override the default used by GA (`document.referrer`) in your GA code by setting

`_gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', 'referring url here']);`

This should go before the `_trackPageview` call.

Comment: Thanks for the the tip.  I'm trying to solve this server side, and wondering if a solution can be formed directly in the controller action.  This is a pretty unique edge case for handling the redirect from the the action..